# Displaying an image on Chromecast Custom Receiver

Tags: javascript, chromecast

I have downloaded the sample custom receiver available [here](https://github.com/googlecast/CastReferencePlayer). It works well for audio and video, but I can't seem to cast images. I added a IMAGE Type to the '`sampleplayer.Type`' enum and tried adding a  tag in the html file of the player ( just like the one for video ), but every time I try to display an image I get '`Load metadata error: [object Object]`'.

I tried making a custom skin receiver since images get displayed with that one, but I can't seem to find any differences between the player.js that I have and the one that is loaded with the custom skin.

Can anyone give me a hint as to what i must do in order to display an image? Does it have to be handled like a video? Or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The receiver that you mentioned doesn't support images. You have an option of using the default receiver or styled receiver (which means you don't need to code anything on the receiver side) or if you prefer to have your own receiver, then you need to write your own custom receiver; you can look at our documentations and guides and the reference receiver to see how things are working; in your case, you need to add an image element to your DOM to show the image and wire that to the receiver SDK. It might be easier to use one of the two receivers that I had mentioned if you don't need any custom behavior.

Comment: The reason i need to use a custom receiver is that i need to filter unsupported media formats that cannot be played by the default/styled receiver. I already got the filtering part done, all i need now is to figure out how to do what you mentioned. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Note that filtering can also be doe on the sender devices and is in fact better since it can provide a feedback to user right away.

Comment: The idea behind this action was to have an extra check on the receiver part, because i noticed that unlike https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media#image-formats, it can play more formats such as .3gp, .mkv and so on. So the extra check will be worth wile :). Btw, do you have some exaples on how to add the image element ? (specific to a custom receiver) - or is it something similar to what happens in the case of videos ?

Comment: Not sure how you want to check that on the receiver side, are you going to look at the extension? I don't have a sharable sample but if you are doing photos type app, you might as well add more user-friendly features such as a slideshow, to your app. Note, however, that the Cast SDK's "queue" doesn't really apply to image type media so you won't get much benefit from those APIs but you can easily roll your own messaging between the two, with possibly a background music while a slide show is playing, etc.